# Glow line with andengine

Tags: android, line, andengine, glow

I would like to make a glow line with andengine by using the Line object. I've tried almost everything, i think.. Here is it:

1. As you can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695622/attach-canvas-drawed-line-to-scene-in-android) I was able to attach a glow line to a scene guided by the **CanvasTextureCompositingExample**, that was ok but my project loads many `ITextureRegion` that when the `BitmapTextureAtlas` loads, the objects I want to doesn't. I think it's because for the canvas I need a `BitmapTextureAtlas` and if I want to load from the path assets `BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas`.

   The last thing I tried with this option was

```
this.mGreenTextureRegion=BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "green.png",0,0)
```

but it does not load too.

2. Also tried `CardinalSplineMoveModifier, CubicBezierCurveMoveModifier, QuadraticBezierCurveMoveModifier` Modifiers.

I wast thinking about draw a Canvas first and then load a `BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas`.

Any suggestion would be helpful. thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I think I found the solution, the problem was with the andengine line that is drawed, it seems ugly with pixels, so i wanted to those pixels go away and make a pretty smooth line. Maybe someone hit my problem, here's the solution:

`@Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        final Camera camera = new Camera(0,0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        EngineOptions options = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
        options.getRenderOptions().setMultiSampling(true);//this make the smooth line
        return options;
    }`